# Double and float may have the same precision?

Tags: c, floating-point, double-precision

I have to implements a program that calculate the machine epsilon for **float** and **double**.
I wrote these functions:

```
int feps(){
    //machine epsilon for float
    float tmp=1;
    int d=0;
    while(1+(tmp=tmp/2)>1.0f)d++;
    return d;
}

int deps(){
    //machine epsilon for double
    double tmp=1;
    int d=0;
    while(1+(tmp=tmp/2)>1.0)d++;
    return d;
}
```

**Note**:
64 bit machine compiler gcc 4.9.1 target: x86_64-linux-gnu
32 bit machine compiler gcc 4.8.2 target: i686-linux-gnu
I tried it in a **64** bit machine and the results are:
Float 23
Double 52
As I expected, then I tried it in a **32** bit virtual machine and the results were very strange:
Float 63
Double 63
I also tried to compile my program with **-mpc32**, **-mpc64** and **-mpc80** and these are the result:
**-mpc32** Float 23, Double 23
**-mpc64** Float 52, Double 52
**-mpc80** Float 63, Double 63
I also tried these compilation option in the 64 bit machine but the results were always 23 and 52.
I know that float are single precision and double are double precision but it's possible that the compiler of my 32 bit virtual machine use a [binary80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) format for both float and double?

I'm quite sure my code is correct so I think that the problem is something related with compiler or something more subtle.
I've spend the entire day searching information about floating point and I've read something about MMX/SSE instruction but I didn't understand a lot, and something about x87 FPU that may create some problem.

---

**Update:**
I want to thank everyone who helped me, I managed to get the real epsilon value for float and double in the 32 bit virtual machine, that's the code:

```
int feps(){
    float tmp=1;
    int d=0;
    float tmp2=1;
    do{
        tmp2=1+(tmp=tmp/2);
        d++;
    }while(tmp2>1.0f);
    return d-1;
}

int deps(){
    double tmp=1;
    int d=0;
    double tmp2=1;
    do{
        tmp2=1+(tmp=tmp/2);
        d++;
    }while(tmp2>1.0);
    return d-1;
}
```

as you can see we need to put the intermediate result into a variable, in that way we can prevent that 1+(tmp=tmp/2) is evaluated as a **long double** in the cycle test.

Comment: It is compiler and implementation specific. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: perhaps it's something to do with your virtual machine's processing of floating point instructions

Comment: On your x86 machine [FLT_EVAL_METHOD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD) is 2, but on x86_64 it is 0. See the linked site for descriptions.

Comment: Try `printf("%zu\n",sizeof(float));`. That won't tell you what epsilon is, but will tell you how many bytes a `float` has on the virtual machine.

Comment: @cremno the assignment should force the result to be converted to `float` so I don't quite see how that would be a complete explanation

Comment: Try printing the `FLT_EPSILON` and `DBL_EPSILON` constants defined in `<float.h>` on all these platforms.  `float` and `double` may actually be the same type.

Comment: I've tried the printf with %zu and in every case the result is 4 bytes for float and 8 bytes for double.

Comment: Your indentation style is highly misleading ;-)

Comment: @LolloFake: How do you compile your code? What options do you use?

Comment: @cremno gcc es3.c for the 64 bit machine, for the 32 bit machine I've tried gcc -mpcXX es3.c where XX is 32,64 or 80. I've also printed FLT_EPSILON and DBL_EPSILON, the values are different.

Comment: What *may* help is declaring `tmp` as `volatile`. This should prevent the variable from being "cached" in a register and can avoid issues with excess precision when computing on x87 FPUs.

Comment: You may be getting fooled by values being kept in a floating point register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the 32-bit platform, ABI constraints make it simpler to use historical floating-point registers; as a consequence, the compiler defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` as 2. This is how you get:

```
Float 63
Double 63
```

In short, when `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is defined to 2 by the compiler, as is the case on your 32-bit virtual machine, floating-point expressions and constants [are evaluated to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#IEEE.C2.A0754_floating_point_support) the precision of `long double`, regardless of their types, and only assignments to lvalues and explicit casts round the computed values from `long double` to the actual floating-point type. There are no such constructs at toplevel of the expression `1+(tmp=tmp/2)`, so the addition is evaluated to the precision of `long double`.

This two-post [series](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/06/On-the-precise-analysis-of-C-programs-for-FLT_EVAL_METHOD-2) shows some examples on which `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` makes a difference in addition to yours. GCC's behavior is deterministic, and according to the explanation laid out by J.S.Myers. Clang's behavior is nondeterministic (then and now) and developers have little interest in improving this mode of their compiler.

Comment: `tmp` is an lvalue, so `tmp = tmp/2` is an assignment to lvalue, which should force the rounding.  The result of an *assignment-expression* has the type of the left-hand operand (not the raw result of the right-hand-side)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, but `float` has way enough range to represent `long double`'s machine epsilon (and indeed it does in the OP's program). The important thing is that `+` in `1+…` is a double-extended addition between the double-extended 1 and the conversion to double-extended of the value of `tmp`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have rephrased the sentence you were referring to.

Comment: could you explain in more detail (perhaps with standard references) why a "top level" assignment is different to another assignment?

Comment: @MattMcNabb in `1.0f + (y = e)`, the rule that assignments and casts remove the extra precision when `FLT_EVAL_METHOD > 0` only applies to `y = e`. The addition is still done with the extra precision implied by the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`. This is all I mean.

Comment: OK. I was assuming that `tmp/2` is the main purpose of this loop and the `+1` made no difference, but in fact perhaps the `+` is also significant.